# Groovy: Duplicate values displayed multiple times

Tags: groovy, duplicates, hashset

I’m attempting to retrieve and display the duplicate values from a txt file through groovy, and when I use the following code snippet I am able to retrieve all the values I need and their duplicate values; however, when the output is displayed it shows any value with more than two occurrences two+ times rather than just one time. I have attached the output to provide a better visualization of what I am encountering. Any guidance is appreciated!

```
 //Find and display duplicate values
    Set<String> store = new HashSet<>()
    for (String num : phones){
        if (!store.add(num)){
            println("Duplicate Number: " + num + " : " + phones.count(num) + " instances")
    }
    }

Output:

Duplicate Number: 567-567-5678 : 3 instances
Duplicate Number: 877-898-8767 : 4 instances
Duplicate Number: 877-898-8767 : 4 instances
Duplicate Number: 789-987-7890 : 2 instances
Duplicate Number: 567-567-5678 : 3 instances
Duplicate Number: 456-567-8907 : 2 instances
Duplicate Number: 877-898-8767 : 4 instances
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print out the number only when it's being added for the first time:

```
Set<String> store = new HashSet<>()
for (String num : phones){
    def count = phones.count(num)
    if (store.add(num) && count > 1) {
        println("Duplicate Number: " + num + " : " + count + " instances")
    }
}
```

With Groovy it's actually a one-liner:

```
phones.countBy { it }.findAll { it.value > 1 }.each { k, v -> println "Dup: $k: $v times" }
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the clarification!